# Migrating a database from SQL Server 2012 to the cloud

Tags: sql-server, migration, cloud, aws

I have a sample SQL Server database which is running on my computer. I have a cloud database account on AWS (free account). I want to migrate the database, with all tables, to the cloud.

How can I do that? Are there any open-source or free tools?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Importing Data Into SQLServer on Amazon RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html).

Also, from codeplex [SQL Database Migration Wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) with a reference [video](http://lynnlangit.com/2012/05/17/aws-rds-sql-server-vs-sql-azure-smackdown-importing-data/) as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can [try out](http://www.nuodb.com/techblog/2013/04/26/getting-started-migrate-a-database-from-sql-server-to-nuodb/) with nuodb.com as it has some simple steps wherein you can migrate your database from SQL Server to cloud. You just need to download some simple application which is free of cost and follow some simple instructions on how to install and use it.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to change the RDBMS itself..